# Independence of the sum of two dice given one of them is odd the result

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I'm not sure how to argue this.

Two fair dice, one red and one blue are rolled. 
Let $A$ be the event that the number rolled on the red die is odd. 
Let $B$ be the event that the number rolled on the blue die is odd. 
Let $C$ be the event that the sum of the two dice is odd. 
Show that $B$ and $C$ are independent.

It's obvious that $A$ & $B$ are independent 
I tried 
$$P(C \mid B) = P(\text{Die Red + Die Blue is odd} \mid B) = \frac{P(\text{Die Red + Die Blue is odd} \cap B)}{P( B )}$$
If $B$ is odd, Die Red should be Even. Therefore, the sum will be Odd. 
$$\frac{P(A^{c}B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A^{c})P(B)}{P(B)}= \frac{1}{2}$$

If someone has a suggestion, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Isn't that just as simple as applying the definition? $P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)=\frac14$.

Comment: I don't see it that simple. Can you explain me?

Comment: x @Bren: What is your problem with this? Do you not agree that the definition of "$B$ and $C$ are independent" is "$P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$"? Do you not agree that $P(B\cap C)=\frac 14$? Do you not agree that $P(B)P(C)=\frac 14$? Do you not agree that probabilities that both equal $\frac14$ will also equal each other? Give me something to work with here.

Comment: I'm guessing these are regular six sided dice ?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the die is odd if one die is odd and the other is even.

Then the event of the red die being odd *and* the sum being odd, is the same event as the red die being odd *and* the blue die being even.   And such.

Thus $(A \cap C) = (A\cap B^\complement)$ and $(B\cap C)=(B\cap A^\complement)$.

So...

---

Hint: $\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)$ by the Law of Total Probability